# Keras Sequence ImageDatagenerator performance difference when returning X,y in one array and in two arrays

Tags: keras, tensorflow-datasets

I observed a weird performance difference and was curious to find out why it occurs.

I wrote a very simple custom datagenerator extending the [Sequence class](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py#L409-L484) in keras.

Now when I return X (which are images) and y (integer labels) in two seperate arrays
I have about 2x the epoch time than
when I return `np.stack([X, y])` .
Looking through the source, it seems like it shouldn't matter.

Is this due to some way the fit function calls the generator?

thank you for helping!